# Phonegap blackberry10

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

snow@Snow-PC:/media/snow/HDD/BlackBerry$ qde

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6bf42e7, pid=14929, tid=1679051584

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-x86 )

Problematic frame:
V  [libjvm.so+0x2772e7]  instanceKlass::oop_follow_contents(oopDesc*)+0x117

Core dump written. Default location: /media/snow/HDD/BlackBerry/core or core.14929

An error report file with more information is saved as:
/media/snow/HDD/BlackBerry/hs_err_pid14929.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Aborted (core dumped)